# EF 6 Code first from existing database integration tests : database creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, integration-testing, entity-framework-migrations

On the software I'm working on we're switching from Db first to Code first. We sometimes need to update the database, so I was trying to implement migrations.
When I create the InitialCreate migration I have to create it using -IgnoreChanges, since I would like to use the "MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" initializer in my application to keep the database up to date.
This works fine.

We have some integration tests where we use a custom "DropCreateDatabaseAlways" initializer.

The problem is, when the database is created in the Test initialization, it no longer creates it based on the model, but it's created based only the migrations. Result: Empty database because the InitialCreate migration is empty.
If I create the InitialCreate migration without -IgnoreChanges the test database is created as expected, but then I can't use "MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion" in my application, because it wouldn't be able to run it.

Can I generate the test database from the model as if the migrations were off?

I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Integration tests need data in a known data state, even with EF building a schema you need to populate that data for each test. The option I use for integration tests is that I maintain a test database specifically for integration tests which is backed up as I expand scenarios. Each integration test suite restores a fresh copy of the database which has dedicated records for each test scenario and a reasonable data size for measuring metrics through the run. (Help spot performance surprises getting introduced)

Comment: We already used integration tests before switching to code first, I know how they work.
For now our objective is to be able to create a new database for each test executed, add the data we need, and then delete the database entirely. We found this approach to be more reliable.